# Is the balanced parentheses language inherently ambiguous?

Tags: formal-grammars

I have this grammar:

$S\rightarrow SS |S \rightarrow(S)|S\rightarrow\epsilon  $

Now this grammar generates the set of balanced parentheses. But this grammar is ambiguous. I am trying to find an unambiguous grammar for this language but all in vain. This has led me to believe that the language is inherently ambiguous. Am I true? If not please provide an unambiguous grammar for this language.

Comment: Since a DPDA is almost trivial, the language is clearly not inherently ambiguous. And, from this DPDA, you also get a grammar using the standard construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$S \rightarrow (S)S$$
$$S \rightarrow \epsilon$$

Generalising this to other Dyck languages is left as an exercise.